# Add Fallback to CircuitBreaker with Callable

Tags: resilience4j

I am using Spring `JmsTemplate` to send messages. I want to introduce `resilience4j` to allow me to use a Fallback so when the first call fails, it sends the message using another `JmsTemplate` with a different configuration.

I have a this method:

```
void sendMessage(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate, String body) {
    jmsTemplate.send(...);
}
```

The problem is that `Decorators.ofCallable` or `Decorators.ofConsumer` does not give me the `withFallback` option
I can use the following if I change the `sendMessage` method to return some String.

```
Decorators.ofCallable(() -> sendMessage(primaryJmsTemplate, body))
    .withFallback(s -> sendMessage(secondaryJmsTemplate, body))
    .withCircuitBreaker(circuitBreaker).call();
```

I would rather not return a random value just to get this to work. Is there a reason why callable/consumer does not allow Fallback? Or is there a different way to achieve what I want using `resilience4j`?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach with this as I misunderstood what `withFallback` will achieve.

I now use the following:

```
try {
    circuitBreaker.executeRunnable(() -> sendMessage(primaryJmsTemplate, body));
} catch (Exception e) {
    sendMessage(secondaryJmsTemplate, body);
}
```

It results in closing the circuit when calls to primary fail. And then goes to secondary for a period until it retries primary again.